# Should I be creating ChannelFactory<T> in every webpage that needs to call the services?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have ~10 webpages which all need to call methods of ICalculatorService and IShoppingCartService They both are WCF services.

I have an interface referenece of ICalculatorService and IShoppingCartService service.

I am creating an instance of `ChannelFactory<ICalculatorService>` and `ChannelFactory<IShoppingCartService>` in all of the webpages' PageLoad method.

But this is really slowing webpages down and I don't know if this is the best thing to do?

Is there a better way to do implement this functionality?

Comment: What version are you using?  In my experience, performance in creating factories was improved *dramatically* in .Net 4.0.

Comment: Hmm, then are you sure this is the culprit?  On my site, I instantiate the factories on each request and performance is fine.  I benchmarked doing so and was able to execute thousands of services / second, creating the factory/channel each time.

Comment: really, so you think it's fine to do?

Comment: and that's the only option i've got in terms of performance

Comment: I've done performance and memory profiling on this solution.  Caching the channel factory will actually ultimately lead to a memory leak.  Caching the channel requires tricky code to handle broken connections.   I've found that creating both the factory and channel as needed performs great.  So I'm left to wonder:  *how did you come to the conclusion that it was the channel factory code that is slowing you down*?

Comment: @KirkWoll - Are you saying a broken connection leads to memory leaks for a cached channel factory?  That doesn't make sense to me - I could see broken connections (channel) causing a memory leak (if they're not aborted), but not the channel factory itself.   I cache channel factories in my apps at work, and have never seen a problem - but then I use an "open channel, do operation, close/abort channel" approach (in .NET 3.5).

Comment: The big question is: what led you to believe that the channel factory creation has any impact of the performance of the pages?

Comment: @Tim, I should have said, you'll see a memory leak unless you properly abort/dispose the channel after use.  When you create the factory each time, I've found that you don't have to worry about that.  Broken connections are a separate issue when caching the *channels* -- they require special handling in order to dispose of the channel when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a simple IHttpModule to manage all the channel factories so they are available for the duration of the web application and can be shared across all pages.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the improvements @Kirk Woll says regarding 4.0, as we're still on 3.5 at work (I've recommended an upgrade path for our team, but haven't got the go-ahead yet).

Two things I would do, if it is truly the Channel Factory (a point of debate in the comments) or it's the only option you have available (for reasons beyond your control) to tweak the performance (and I know Kirk will probably disagree with me :) ):

1. Only create the Channel Factory on the page during the initial page load - put it in session and pull it back out on postbacks.  You could also put it in cache and simply do a check in the cache at page load (regardless of postback status) since once it's created the first time it'll be available until the cache expires.
2. Cache the Channel Factories at application startup (you can do this in the Global.asax code-behind).

I would favor option 2 if I were to use either of these options.

Answer (score 0):

As the initial comments indicate, you should verify that the ChannelFactory creation is really where the performance issues are coming from. This was definitely an issue with 3.5.

This is what I use, initially implemented in the 3.5 days. This will cache the ChannelFactory, handle any faults at the channel factory level, as well as manage creating a channel for each send request and properly close out the channel. Code below for this class.

Use it like this:

Create a single ServerProxyFactory for each service you need to communicate with. Cache this at your favorite location to persist singletons (@Tim has some good suggestions).

e.g.

```
var cachedCalculatorService = new ServerProxyFactory<ICalculatorService>("endpointName");
```

Use this cached object to call your service. Assume ICalculatorService has an add operation that takes two numbers and returns their sum. Call it like this:

```
var sum = cachedCalculatorService.Send(proxy => proxy.Add(2, 2));
```

The ServerChannelFactory is thread safe, so you can reuse it in as many threads as you want.

Hope this helps.

Here's the code:

```
namespace WcfHelper
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using Microsoft.Commerce.Marketplace.Common.Util;

    /// <summary>
    /// A WCF Proxy Factory suitable for server to server web service calls. A new channel will be created for all service communication.
    /// 
    /// All sends handle disposing of the Proxy channel properly. If the Proxy is requested directly, the caller is responsible for properly 
    /// closing/disposing it.
    /// </summary>
    public class ServerProxyFactory<TContract> : IDisposable where TContract : class
    {
        private readonly object syncObject = new object();

        public ServerProxyFactory(string endpointConfigurationName)
        {
            endpointConfigurationName.EnsureArgNotNullOrEmpty("endPointConfigurationName");
            this.endPointConfigurationName = endpointConfigurationName;
        }

        private readonly string endPointConfigurationName;

        private ChannelFactory<TContract> channelFactory;

        protected ChannelFactory<TContract> ChannelFactory
        {
            get { return this.channelFactory; }
            set
            {
                ChannelFactory<TContract> oldFactory;

                lock (this.syncObject)
                {
                    oldFactory = this.channelFactory;

                    if (oldFactory != null)
                    {
                        oldFactory.Faulted -= this.ChannelFactory_Faulted;
                    }

                    var newChannelFactory = value;
                    if (newChannelFactory != null)
                    {
                        newChannelFactory.Faulted += this.ChannelFactory_Faulted;
                    }

                    this.channelFactory = newChannelFactory;
                }

                if (oldFactory != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ((IDisposable)oldFactory).Dispose();
                    }
                    catch (CommunicationException)
                    {
                        oldFactory.Abort();
                    }
                    catch (TimeoutException)
                    {
                        oldFactory.Abort();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        oldFactory.Abort();
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        protected TContract Proxy
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.disposed)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        "A new Proxy was requested after the ServerProxyFactory has been disposed.");
                }

                if (this.ChannelFactory == null)
                {
                    this.ChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<TContract>(this.endPointConfigurationName);
                }

                return this.ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Perform a WCF call specified by serviceCall delegate 
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TResult"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="serviceCallDelegate"></param>
        /// <returns>return value returned by the WCF call</returns>
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1800:DoNotCastUnnecessarily")]
        public virtual TResult Send<TResult>(Func<TContract, TResult> serviceCallDelegate)
        {
            TResult result;
            TContract proxy = this.Proxy;
            try
            {
                result = serviceCallDelegate(proxy);
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    ((IDisposable)proxy).Dispose();
                }
                catch (CommunicationException)
                {
                    ((ICommunicationObject)proxy).Abort();
                }
                catch (TimeoutException)
                {
                    ((ICommunicationObject)proxy).Abort();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    ((ICommunicationObject)proxy).Abort();
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Perform a WCF call specified by serviceCall delegate 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceCallDelegate"></param>
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1800:DoNotCastUnnecessarily")]
        public virtual void Send(Action<TContract> serviceCallDelegate)
        {
            TContract proxy = this.Proxy;
            try
            {
                serviceCallDelegate(proxy);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (proxy != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ((IDisposable)proxy).Dispose();
                    }
                    catch (CommunicationException)
                    {
                        ((ICommunicationObject)proxy).Abort();
                    }
                    catch (TimeoutException)
                    {
                        ((ICommunicationObject)proxy).Abort();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        ((ICommunicationObject)proxy).Abort();
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void ChannelFactory_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var factory = (ICommunicationObject)sender;
            if (factory == this.ChannelFactory)
            {
                this.ChannelFactory = null;
            }
        }

        #region IDisposable Members

        // Track whether Dispose has been called.
        private bool disposed;

        // Implement IDisposable.
        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                this.ChannelFactory = null;
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```